# How to embed single tweets from twitter on my local website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

i'm try to embed a single tweet post on my page html on my computer
i have just simple html and css page and when i embed the code from twitter
this is the code:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
            <p lang="en" dir="ltr">ICYMI: Lakers&#39; Kobe Bryant &quot;proud of&quot; ranking 2nd on franchise&#39;s all-time assists list <a href="https://t.co/mZZfQ1SQAV">https://t.co/mZZfQ1SQAV</a></p>&mdash; Mark Medina (@MarkG_Medina) <a href="https://twitter.com/MarkG_Medina/status/689111667775504386">January 18, 2016</a></blockquote>
            <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

the result on browser is like this, no icons no styles no button follow

[image]

**i have the result of embed tweet like this**

[image]

thank you,

check this snippet

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
          <p lang="en" dir="ltr">ICYMI: Lakers&#39; Kobe Bryant &quot;proud of&quot; ranking 2nd on franchise&#39;s all-time assists list <a href="https://t.co/mZZfQ1SQAV">https://t.co/mZZfQ1SQAV</a></p>&mdash; Mark Medina (@MarkG_Medina) <a href="https://twitter.com/MarkG_Medina/status/689111667775504386">January 18, 2016</a></blockquote>
          <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Is this right? `src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"`

Comment: thank you so much now is working fine i don't check if https: is existed

but i find this code on twitter, this help without add https:
  
`<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
     js = d.createElement(s);
     js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    
     t._e = [];
     t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
     };
    
     return t;
   }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
  </script>`